# Saving contenteditable Content Changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, contenteditable

Good Day! I am a newbie in asp.net MVC 5 and is working on a form where one cell is editable then it will be saved in the database, along with the values of the other cells. I've managed to make the cell editable using **contenteditable="true"** . This is my View:

```html
<div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">

                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CUSTOMER_ID, "Customer Name", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.DropDownList("CUSTOMER_ID", ViewBag.CustomerName as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "--Select Customer--", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ORDER_DUE_DATE, "Due Date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-lg-5" })
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ORDER_DUE_DATE, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", @type = "date" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ORDER_DUE_DATE, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>


                </div><!--form-horizontal-->



            </div>

        </div><!--col lg 12-->



        <table id="tbl_orderItems" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>

                    <th>Unit</th>
                    <th>Item Description</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            @if (TempData["listOrder"] != null)
            {
                foreach (var items in TempData["listOrder"] as List<ebms.ViewModels.OrderItems>)
                {  @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => items.Id)
                <tr>

                    <td>@items.PRODUCT_CODE</td>
                    <td contenteditable="true">@items.iQuantity</td>
                    <td>@items.MEASUREMENT_NAME</td>
                    <td>@items.ITEM_DESCRIPTION</td>
                    <td>@items.tmpStatus</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = items.Id },
                                        new { onclick = "return confirm('Are sure want to remove?');" })
                    </td>
                </tr>

                }


            }

        </table>

        <div id="menu1">
            <ul>

                <li>
                    <center><a>Select an Item</a></center>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='@Url.Action("Products", "Sales")'>Products </a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>





        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-3 pull-right">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>



    }
</div>
```

I've put the **contenteditable="true"** in the quantity because it is the cell that should be editable. Most of the other values in there are from this form: [image]

It will then be passed on to this form and the quantity should be editable. 
[image]

Then the Customer will be chosen and the Order Due Date will be put in there as well. My problem is, the value that is typed to the editable cell is not saved in to the database. Can someone help me on how to use **contenteditable="true"** properly and then save it to the database? Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Why are you using content editable instead of a form control? Are you submitting this using ajax?

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke ! I used content editable to make the Quantity Cell editable. Before I had the editable cell, I had no trouble saving the **Orders** from using a method in the controller.